# Functioning of Intent.action_pick_activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

Here is I would like to set up in my application, the function of sharing (facebook, twitter, e-mail) as that of YouTube for example but I get lost little.
By looking I saw that apparently it would be necessary to use Intent.action_pick_activity but I do not manage to see how using it on my case.

What is that somebody has already implemented this kind of thing? Either what is what somebody knows where I can find examples??
Thanks to all!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that [ACTION_PICK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PICK) will help you out.

[Here](http://www.openintents.org/en/node/263) is a sample code of how to use it.

Comment: Thank you for your answers!
And indeed for what I want to realize it is necessary to use ACTION_SEND and createChooser ()

Answer (score 0):

I [blogged](http://www.androidguys.com/2009/11/02/a-call-to-action-action_send-that-is/) about using `ACTION_SEND` and `createChooser()` for sharing. I do not believe that `ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY` has a role here.